# How to edit horizantal drop down menu

Tags: html, css

I am learning to create a website and using a pre-created HTML template so i would like to know how to get the drop down menu with the existing menu style cause the existing menu style the color and everything is very suitable to the whole site but it doesnot really allow me to get any drop down menus

so i am guessing i need to use javascript and some css magic.
So here is the code in the html file until the menu code

```
     <head>
       <title>Home</title>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
      <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
       <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="js/easySlider1.5.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/stuHover.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
       // <![CDATA[
        $(document).ready(function(){   
    $("#slider").easySlider({
        controlsBefore: '<p id="controls">',
        controlsAfter:  '</p>',
        auto: true, 
        continuous: true
    }); 
      });
     // ]]>
         </script>
      <style type="text/css">
      .gallery { width:890px; height:326px; margin:0 auto; }
         #slider { margin:0; padding:0; list-style:none; }
           #slider ul,
          #slider li { margin:0; padding:0; list-style:none; }
        /* 
           define width and height of list item (slide)
         entire slider area will adjust according to the parameters provided here
           */
          #slider li { width:890px; height:326px; overflow:hidden; }
         p#controls { margin:0; padding:0; position:relative; }                                   #prevBtn { display:block; margin:0;                               overflow:hidden;    width:32px;             height:66px; position:absolute; left:-41px; top:-200px; }
     #nextBtn { display:block; margin:0; overflow:hidden; width:32px;  height:66px;        position:absolute; left: 906px; top:-200px; }
    #prevBtn a { display:block; width:32px; height:66px; background:url(images/l_arrow.gif) no-repeat 0 0; }
      #nextBtn a { display:block; width:32px; height:66px; background:url(images/r_arrow.gif) no-repeat 0 0; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="main">
  <div class="blok_header">
    <div class="header">
      <div class="logo"><a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.gif" width="309" height="109" border="0" alt="logo" /></a></div>
      <div class="simple_text"><a href="#">Email</a> | <a href="#">Client Login</a></div>
      <div class="search">
        <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
          <label>
            <input name="q" type="text" class="keywords" id="textfield" maxlength="50" value="Search..." />
            <input name="b" type="image" src="images/search.gif" class="button" />
          </label>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="clr"></div>
      <div class="menu">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="index.html" class="active">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
          <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
          <li><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
          <li><a href="contact.html">Contact us</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

this is the css code

```
         @charset "utf-8";
body { margin:0; padding:0; width:100%; background: #fff;}
html { padding:0; margin:0;}

a { text-decoration:none;}
a:hover { text-decoration:underline;}
/* main */
.main { padding:0; margin:0 auto;}
.main h2 { font: bold 17px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#ffffff; margin:5px 0; padding:10px 5px; border-bottom:1px solid #296c78;}
/********** header **********/
.blok_header { margin:0; padding:0; background:url(images/header_bg.gif) top repeat-x;}
.header { width:1000px; margin:0 auto; padding:0;}
.header img.twitter { float:right; margin:2px; padding:0;}
/* logo */
.logo { padding:0; margin:0; width:309px; float:left;}
/* simple_text */
.simple_text { text-align:right; font: normal 14px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#737a7f; width:550px; float:right; padding:2px; margin:0;}
.simple_text a { font: normal 11px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#fff; text-decoration:none;}
.simple_text a:hover { text-decoration:underline;}
/* search */
.search { padding:10px 0 0 0; margin:5px 0; width:220px; float:right;}
.search span { display:block; float:left;}
.search form { display:block; float:left; padding:5px 0;}
.search form .keywords { float:left; background: url(images/search_bg.gif) left top no-repeat; border:0; height:14px; width:180px; padding:5px 5px; margin:0; font:normal 11px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#a1a1a1;}
.search form .button { float:left; margin:0; padding:0;}
/* menu     */
.menu { padding:3px 0 0 0; margin:0; width:450px; float:left; height:65px;}
.menu ul { padding:0; margin:0; list-style:none; float:left; border:0;}
.menu ul li { float:left; margin:0; padding:0 5px; border:0;}

.menu li:hover ul { display: block; position: absolute; }
.menu li:hover li { float: none;font-size: 11px;    }
.menu li:hover a { background: #617F8A; }
.menu li:hover li a:hover { background: #95A9B1; }
.menu ul li a { text-transform:uppercase; float:left; margin:0; padding:25px 15px; color:#fff; font:normal 11px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; text-decoration:none;}
.menu ul li a:hover { background: url(images/hover.gif) repeat-x right;}
.menu ul li a.active {background:url(images/hover.gif) repeat-x right;}
       /* sub-menus*/


/*header_text*/
.header_text { height:326px; margin:0; padding:0; background:url(images/slider_bg.gif) top center repeat-x;}
.header_text_resize {  width:982px; margin:0 auto; padding:0; }
.header_text .div { float:right; width:890px; padding:10px 0; margin:0;}
.header_text img.screen { float:left; margin:9px 0 0 0;}
.header_text .div .left1 { float:right; width:600px; padding:0; margin:0;}
.header_text .div .left1 img { float:left; padding:0 20px 0 10px; margin:0;}
.header_text .div .left1 h2 { border:0; font:bold 36px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#fff; padding:10px; margin:0; text-transform:uppercase;}
.header_text .div .left1 h2 span {
    color:#01355d;
}
.header_text p { font: normal 11px   Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#fff; padding:10px; margin:0;}
.header_text p span { font: bold 18px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#fff;}
/* header_text2 */
.header_text2 {height:144px; margin:0; padding:0; background:url(images/slider_bg2.gif) top center repeat-x;}
.header_text_resize2 {  width:982px; margin:0 auto; padding:0; }
.header_text2 h2 { width:300px; float:left; font:bold 36px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#fff; padding:50px 0 0 0; margin:0; text-transform:uppercase; border:0;}
.header_text2 p { width:600px; float:left; font: normal 11px   Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#fff; padding:53px 0 0 0; margin:0;}
.header_text2 p span { font: bold 18px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#fff;}
/********** body **********/
.body_resize { margin:0; padding:0;}
.body { width:1000px;  margin:0 auto; padding:0;}
.body h2 { border:0; font: normal 24px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#0b4f7d; margin:0 0 10px 0; padding:15px 5px; border-bottom:1px solid #d3d6d8;}
.body img { float:left; padding:0; margin:10px;}
.body img.floated { float:right; padding:0; margin:10px;}
.body p { font:normal 11px  Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#5d5d5d; line-height:1.8em; padding:5px; margin:0;}
.body p span { font: bold 11px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#3f3f3f;}
.body em { font: italic 11px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#525252;}
.body a { text-decoration:underline; color:#7daf0e; line-height:1.8em;}
.body_small { width:300px; float:left; margin:0; padding:20px;}
.body_small p.test { height:143px; background:url(images/test.gif) top no-repeat; width:239px; padding:10px 15px; margin:10px 0;}
.body_small p.borded { border:1px solid #c3c7ca;}
.body_big { width:620px; float:left; margin:0; padding:20px;}
/* Navigation */    
ul.Navigation { padding:0; margin:0 40px 0 0; list-style:none; border:0;}
ul.Navigation li { margin:0; padding:3px 10px; border:0; line-height:0px;}
ul.Navigation li a { display:block; padding:5px 0 5px 25px; border-bottom:1px dashed #c4c4c4; background:url(images/sub_ul_li.gif) 10px center no-repeat; color:#737373; font:normal 11px  Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; text-decoration:none; line-height:1.6em;}
ul.Navigation li a:hover {  text-decoration:underline;}
ul.Navigation li a.active { text-decoration:underline;}
/*buttonss*/
.buttonss { width:150px; float:right; margin:10px; padding:5px;}
.buttonss a { border:1px solid #d6d6d6; background:#96148f; font: normal 11px   Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; color:#fff; padding:1px 4px; margin:2px 1px; text-decoration:none;}
.buttonss a:hover {text-decoration:none; color:#fff; background:#5e1496;}
/* END_bloga*/
/* FBG */
.FBG_top {background:#1d2226 url(images/FGB_bg.gif) top repeat-x; margin:0; padding:0;}
.FBG {  margin:0 auto; padding:0; width:1000px;}
.FBG_resize { width:290px; float:left; margin:15px 0; padding:20px;}
.FBG_resize2 { border-right:1px dashed #33393e; border-left:1px dashed #33393e; width:290px; float:left; margin:15px 0; padding:20px;}
.FBG h2 { border:0; font: normal 24px  Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#fff; padding:15px 5px; margin:0;}
.FBG p { font: normal 11px  Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#fefdfe; padding:5px; margin:0; line-height:1.8em;}
.FBG img { float:left; margin:0; padding:5px 10px;}
/********** footer **********/
.footer { margin:0; padding:0; height:76px; background:#14181b; border-top:1px solid #2b3136;}
.footer_resize { margin:0 auto; padding:0; width:1000px;}
.footer ul { margin:0; padding:30px 10px 10px 10px; list-style:none; float:left;}
.footer img { display:inline; margin:5px 10px; padding:0;}
.footer ul li { margin:0; padding:0 10px; float:left;}
.footer p { margin:0; padding:30px 20px 10px 20px; float:right; color:#373d42; font:normal 11px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; line-height:1.8em;}
.footer a { color:#46820d; font:normal 11px Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; text-decoration:none; line-height:1.8em;}
.footer a:hover { text-decoration:underline;}
/********** contact form **********/
.form { float:left; width:560px; margin-top:40px; margin-left:10px;}
/********** contact form **********/
#contactform { margin:0; padding:5px 10px;}
#contactform * { color:#F00;}
#contactform ol { margin:0; padding:0; list-style:none;}
#contactform li { margin:0; padding:0; background:none; border:none; display:block;}
#contactform li.buttons { margin:5px 0 5px 0;}
#contactform label { float:left; margin:0; width:100px; padding:5px 0; font:normal 13px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#6e6e6e; text-transform:capitalize;}
#contactform label span { font:normal 10px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
#contactform input.text { width:430px; border:1px solid #c5c5c5; margin:5px 0; padding:5px 2px; height:15px; background:#fff;}
#contactform textarea { width:430px; border:1px solid #c5c5c5; margin:10px 0; padding:2px; background:#fff; height:250px;}
#contactform li.buttons input { padding:3px 0; margin:0 0 0 100px; border:0; color:#FFF;}
p.response { text-align:center; color:#2c2c2c; font:bold 11px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; line-height:1.8em; width:auto;}

p.clr, .clr { clear:both; padding:0; margin:0;}
li.bg, .bg { clear:both; border-bottom:1px dashed #c7c7c7; padding:10px 0 0 0; margin:0 0 10px 0; background:none; list-style:none;}
li.line, .line { border-top:1px solid #c7c7c7; padding:0; margin:20px 0; background:none; list-style:none;}
```

is there an easy way to get the submenus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would using something like SuckerFish: http://www.htmldog.com/articles/suckerfish/dropdowns/ 
It is probably easier if you put the SuckerFish code on your site, get it working, then adjust accordingly for your template.